# How to get location \usr\sap\<SID>\JC<InstNo>\j2ee\cluster\server<n>\log programmatically using SAP NetWeaver

Tags: jakarta-ee, netweaver

We are using SAP NetWeaver Development Studio for our project. My problem here is I don't know how to get in java code the exact location `\usr\sap\<SID>\JC<InstNo>\j2ee\cluster\server<n>\log`. Currently, I'm hardcoding the code like in below.

```
File file = new File("c:\\usr\\sap\\SID\\JC\\j2ee\\cluster\\server\\log\\log.csv")
```

In my development using Windows, I can successfully write the file locally but I'm wondering how to write in the live SAP server using UNIX environment.

Note that every SAPID is different in every server.

Hope anyone can help me on this and would be much appreciate.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Cluster Information:

```
IClusterInformation clusterInfo = (IClusterInformation) PortalRuntime.getRuntimeResources().getService(IClusterInformation.KEY);
```

then, get the property:

```
clusterInfo.getSAPJ2EEServerDirectory()
```

the result will be similar to this depending on your system, then append the log folder to returned path:

```
C:\usr\sap\J01\J00\j2ee\cluster\server0
```